# Perl. Fetching file from remote server, only core modules

Tags: perl, file, fetch

I need help: is there a way to fetch a file from the remote server using only core modules of perl 5.8.8? File::Fetch became core module only from 5.9.

Comment: `Net::FTP` was released with perl v5.7.3.

Comment: How can I fetch file using Net::FTP without ftp-server on remote server?

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on what you mean by "fetch".

Comment: There is a file on remote server, available by http, I need to download this file from this server, using only core modules of perl 5.8.8

Comment: Well, it seems neither `LWP` or `HTTP::UserAgent` were in core with perl v5.8.8. I'm sure something existed, I just can't find anything. Perl 5.8 is 10 years old by now, so things have changed.

Answer (score 4):

This comes up all the time.  Take a look at the classic [yes, even you can use CPAN](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828).  If you have the ability to create and run a Perl script, then you also have the ability to put a module in your local directory and use it.  The requirement to use only core modules is entirely artificial.

In your case, [`LWP::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/Simple.pm)'s `getstore()` function will do what you want. While it is technically not core, `LWP::Simple` is included by default with many Perl distributions.  You may well already have it.

**Update:** so, you want to do this on 1000 servers?  No need to manually install the module on each server.  [Use CPAN programmatically](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/CPAN.html#Programmer%27s-interface) to download and install the module(s) you need (some tweaking will be needed to get CPAN to install it locally rather than in the root module library).  Also Leon Timmermans's suggestion of fatpacking the module is another option.

If you really don't want to do it this way, then basically the answer is no: there is no simple way to fetch a remote file via HTTP using neither the appropriate modules, nor a system command *(I didn't consider writing your own HTTP client to be a simple method, but that's fine if it works for you)*.

The only other potential solution I see would be a different approach to your problem, such as:

- Using a script in a single location to get the file, then distribute
  it to all 1000 servers via FTP.
- Or, putting the file on an FTP server, then using a simple Perl
  script on each server to fetch it via FTP.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I need to download this file on over 1000 servers, and I can't to install some modules on it. I need simple tiny perl-script running on centos 5, with no outside system calls...

Comment: @user1759997, I have updated my answer to address your objection.

Comment: I've found another one: using IO::Socket::INET I wrote the simple tiny http-client. ;-) (IO::Socket is core module since 5.3

Answer (score 2):

As Dan already said, *yes, even you can use CPAN*. One approach his link doesn't mention is writing it as a normal CPAN-using distribution, and then [fatpack](https://metacpan.org/module/fatpack) it. Fatpacker combines a script with all its (pure-perl) dependencies, creating a single easy to distribute file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
my $wgetoutput = `wget "$myFileToGet"`;
```

Stuff in backticks (`) will be given to the default shell, so you can call whatever you want (and are allowed) there.
Caveat: $myFileToGet could have stuff like "&& rm -rf *" in it, so dont forget to sanitize!

Comment: Thanks, I know about this, but can't use wget by condition =) May be you know another way to download file strictly from perl? (5.8.8)

Comment: No clue then, sorry. I never worked with such limiting environments before, the smallest system i ever used is a GNUblin. :/